# Onetime checkout success page occasionally returns 404 - have to flush cache

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, cache, order-success-page

Once every three weeks or so, our checkout success page (.../checkout/onepage/success/) starts returning a 404. When we notice that has happenned, we have to flush the cache for it to be back online.

- Is that a known issue?
- Can I avoid it? Work around it?
- Should I disable cache for this specific page? How can I do that?

We have Magento 2.4.3-p3 with cache enabled (including full page, layouts and blocks). Not using Redis.

I have owner access to the installation, but limited knowlege of Magento's inner workings.